# Android RecyclerView there is empty gap at the above of the items

Tags: android, android-layout, androiddesignsupport

According to the attached picture, I'm experiencing an empty space with exactly one page height at the above the recyclerview items.
[image: problem illustration of empty gap in recyclerview]

Here is my recyclerview row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            ...

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_list"></include>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        ...
```

I also tried `layout_height="match_parent"` for the `recyclerview` but the only difference was the empty gap shown at the first without any scrolling.
Setting fixed height to the items also didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the dependencies to `recyclerview-v7:25.3.1`, I forced to change all `row_items`'s `layout_height` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`.
In this case I forgot to change the `layout_height` of an `item_row` layout which was my **`header`** row of the `recyclerview`.

Here is my `recyclerview` header row that should have `layout_height="wrap_content"`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```